# window service and sqlserver connection

Tags: sql-server, windows, service

i have a project in window service, when i insert the following code in Onstart() event and debug it manually then database is inserted successfully, but when i create exe file of this project and started it in task manager then does nothing...i mean it didnt save any thing to database.

```
try
                    {
                        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=testing;Integrated Security=True");
                        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        cn.Open();
                        adp.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into testing1 values(1)", cn);
                        adp.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cn.Close();
                    }
                    catch { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the title of your post states "Windows service", I assume your program is running as a service. You are using integrated security, according to your connection string. Check if the account under which this runs has the rights to login to database server, and has the right to execute the insert.

You could of course also change to a fix database user account if your database is configured to allow that and there is one configured.

**Edit**
I also would suggest instead of an empty `catch()` clause, you print out/save to a log file the error message and stack trace to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: thanx for your responce...but here i have changed my connection string. SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=testing;User ID=sa; Password=123"); but still i am geting error

Comment: when i am installing the exe  file of this project...then a messagebox appeard which contain...Username...password, conform password... when i insert these data(sa, 123,123) or (sadqimscience_, 123,123) then it gives error : "Error:no mapping between account name security ids during window service installation"

Comment: I would assume at installation time, the user name and password would be the Windows user and password for the account in whose name the service is running. I would not think this has anything to do with database users if you configured them in the `ConnectionString`.